# In Torch, how to add momentum to my stochastic descent?

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I'm implementing a multi-layer perceptron neural network in Torch, by following [this example](http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/newbieTutorial.html) (from the "Example: training a neural network" to the "Torch basics: testing your neural network" section).

Now I have to add some [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#The_momentum_method) to this neural network model, but I cannot understand how to do it.
The gradient descent part is:

```
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()  
trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(mlp, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.01
trainer:train(dataset)
```

I was wishing there was some command like: trainer.momentum = 1, but there's no such thing.

Does anyone know how to add momentum to my Torch neural network model?

Answer (score 2):

Using the package `optim` (see https://github.com/torch/optim) for optimisation you can make a Lua table for the parameters. Here is an example;

```
optimState = { 
learningRate = 0.001,
weightDecay = 0,
momentum = 0.9,
learningRateDecay = 0 
}
```

Then you can pass this table of parameters into the `optim.method` function (which optimises your loss function), such as;

```
optim.method(func, x, optimState)
```

Comment: Thanks @mattdns. I checked `optim` but it seems a little complicated to me. Should I always define on my own the function `func` and its derivative?

Comment: See http://rnduja.github.io/2015/10/26/deep_learning_with_torch_step_7_optim/. There is function called ```feval``` which you essentially replace ```func``` with. Just edit the code inside ```feval``` slightly to go with your code. You basically but this whole thing inside a for loop which iterates over your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the two things:

- implement SGD by your own - it is very basic algorithm, really. It will take just few lines of torch code and then add momentum
- use other library for training, like `optim` package from `torch` https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/doc/index.md which has multiple training methods, including SGD with momentum

Comment: Thanks @leijot. I already have implemented the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) on my own, but what should I do to add momentum? Here's my code: http://bit.ly/1XyxHFv

Comment: in each step you move your parameters toward negative gradient - momentum simply states "instead of just adding learning_step*gradient move a bit towards **last gradient** too". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Momentum